# getting Cloudformation from an existing AWS Glue Crawler

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-athena, aws-glue

Is there a way to create/get/retrieve the cloudformation resource json/yaml from an existing AWS Glue Crawler? If so, how do I get it. If not, how can I create one from my existing Crawler?

**EDIT:**

Actually we are trying to move from the manually configured crawler to one, that is deployed via cloudformation so that it is easily maintainable. We have a few crawlers and need to migrate them. Thus, the question.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55866147/how-to-add-manually-created-resources-to-the-cloudformation-template/55867641#55867641

Comment: Why not re-create them with CloudFormation? What is the purpose of keeping manually created ones?

Comment: the manually created one, already exists and is working, we want to make sure that we do not create something different.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the AWS CLI you can use the below command to retrieve the crawler information

`aws glue get-crawlers`